# Problem with error C2440 in MS VS 2015

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Первая часть кода:

```
template< typename data_type >
void Agent::set_solution(
const solution_key_t& key,
data_type& data,
std::function< void(data_type&, data_type&) > function,
std::double_t probability)
{
        if (std::find(this->m_solutions.begin(), this->m_solutions.end(), key) == this->m_solutions.end())
        {
            using solution_map_t = std::map< solution_key_t, Solution >;

            this->m_solutions.insert(solution_map_t::value_type(key, Solution()));
        }
        this->m_solutions[key].set_solution< data_type >(data, function, probability);
} // set_solution
```

Вторая часть кода:

```
#define AGENT(id)   System::instance().agents[id]

static const solution_key_t default_key = "key";
static const std::double_t default_probability = 1.0;

#define DEFAULT_LAMBDA_EQ(T)    [](T& to, T& from) { to = from; }

using asset_id_t = std::uint64_t;

auto function_asset_id_smth = [](agent_id_t id)
{
    using T = std::pair< asset_id_t, std::string >;

    T asset_id(static_cast< asset_id_t >(1), static_cast< std::string >("smth"));

    AGENT(id)->set_solution< T >(
        default_key,
        asset_id,
        DEFAULT_LAMBDA_EQ(T),
        default_probability);
}; // function_asset_id_smth
```

Возникает ошибка:
Ошибка  C2440   : невозможно преобразовать "initializer list" в "std::pair" в строке с вставкой нового элемента в map в первом фрагменте кода. Я не вполне понимаю, как трактовать эту ошибку, где-то теряется или добавляется спецификатор const? Или в аргументах при вызове функции следует указывать другие спецификаторы? Как мне кажется, проблема с key в первом фрагменте кода, но я не могу пока установить, какая именно. Для Solution есть конструктор по умолчанию, там все нормально. solution_key_t это std::string.

Comment: Попробуйте создать [mcve]. Чем проще будет пример, тем быстрее можно получить ответ. Может быть даже самостоятельно.

Comment: Вы уверены, что ошибка происходит именно в строке со вставкой? И где объявление `m_solutions`? Почему оно не приведено в вопросе?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема вот в чем:

```
std::find(this->m_solutions.begin(), this->m_solutions.end(), key)
```

Если я правильно понимаю, `m_solutions` - это map, тогда Вы должны использовать `std::find`, где 3 аргумент имеет тип:

```
const std::pair<solution_key_t, Solution>&   // у Вас же - solution_key_t
```

Тогда, или используйте `std::find_if`:

```
std::find_if(m_solutions.cbegin(), m_solutions.cend(), [=](const auto& item) 
    { return item.first == key; });
```

, или используйте непосредственно интерфейс map (что будет более логично в данном случае):

```
m_solutions.find(key)
```